# How to give input file as String in PHP?

Tags: php, string, file

I have been trying to give the input ID as a variable after reading it from a text file "id.txt"  but it prints nothing.

My complete code is here https://rextester.com/UBICD72948

In that link working between line 7 and 11.

The workable code below:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('id.txt');
$sVideoId = "s32eQF3pzrg";
```

But I have been trying below:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('id.txt');
$sVideoId = "(string)$fileContent";
```

Another try was

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('id.txt');
$sVideoId = "$fileContent";
```

It should print the duration of the video like this example: 235 or any integer number

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `$fileContent = (string)file_get_contents('id.txt');`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @paskl, tried it out like this $fileContent = (string)file_get_contents('id.txt');
$sVideoId = "$fileContent"; but no results yet, unfortunately.

Comment: is the id.txt in the same folder of the script, if so then try with:
$fileContent = file_get_contents('./id.txt');
$sVideoId = $fileContent;

Comment: @ Soufiane Lamnizeh, yes everything is on the Desktop. I didn't put them in a folder yet. I just tried your code but still no output. Really feeling sorry because not finding out the bug.

Comment: It looks like you need a bit more information about what is happening when attempting to read the file. What output do you get if you try the following? `$sVideoId = file_get_contents('id.txt');

if ($sVideoId !== false) {
    echo $sVideoId;
}
else {
    print_r(error_get_last());
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I try your code it prints: nfs8NYg7yQM
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/riky/Desktop/New work/youtube_duration.php:1) in /home/riky/Desktop/New work/youtube_duration.php on line 47. On line 47 I have:  header("Content-Type: text/plain");